# Mac OS X : Tomcat not starting

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am using Mac OS X v10.7.3 and trying to install Apache Tomcat on it.

In my machine JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/Home

I download apache-tomcat-6.0.35.tar.gz, unpacked it and placed the folder in /Library.

Now when I run `sudo sh startup.sh` in terminal, i get the following output :

`Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar`

But when I open `http://localhost:8080` , I get Unable to connect error.

What could be going wrong?

-Sudhi

Comment: Do you get a "page not found" error (404) or a can't connect message? It's possible you do not have an index.html file in your http root directory.

Comment: Amir, I got Unable to connect error: Unable to connect
      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.

Comment: Go to $CATALINA_HOME/logs/ and find the newest log file, the name of which starts with "catalina". It should say what went wrong.

Comment: Did your Mac ever ask you if it was okay for the Java process to accept incoming connections? I don't know if the built-in firewall in Mac OS X protects localhost by default.

Comment: @Tom : $CATALINA_HOME is not set in my machine

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz : Mac did not ask that. BTW, I see that my hudson is running on 8080 and its working fine. I stopped it and then started Tomcat, but still it did not work.

Comment: @user1046367 I just meant the tomcat installation directory. It doesn't matter if it's set as an environment variable or not. I should have used a less ambiguous format. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What port(s) are you trying to use for your `<Connectors>` in Tomcat's `server.xml` file? If you are running Hudson in parallel with Tomcat, you'll have to make sure none of them overlap. You said that with Hudson stopped, Tomcat still won't start, so that might not be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

change your directory to `Applications/tomcat/bin`

Then Write `./catalina.sh run`

I hope this will work